# Forward Azure Metrics for very specific resources to DataDog

Tags: azure, metrics, forwarding, datadog

This question may sound a little odd, but here it goes: A customer of ours would like to get access to certain metrics of his environment of our product which we host on Azure for the customer. It's a pretty complicated deployment, but in the end it consists of an Application Gateway, some virtual machines and a dedicated Azure SQL database.

The customer now would want to get select metrics from this deployment forward to their own DataDog subscription, e.g. VM CPU metrics, database statistics and those things. DataDog obviously supports all this information (which is good), but as a default would slurp in information from **all** resources within our subscription (which is not OK).

Is there a way to fine-granularly define which data is forwarded to DataDog, e.g. the resources and also which type of metrics to forward for each resource? What are my options here? Is it enough to create a service principal with a limited reading right, or can I configure this somewhere else? I am unfortunately not familiar with DataDog.

The main thing which must be prevented is that the customer due to the metrics forwarding could get access to other metrics in our subscription - we need to control the exact scope of the metrics.

Answer (score 0):

The pretty straightforward solution to this issue is to create a service principal via command line, and then to assign the monitoring role to this service principal only exactly for the resources you need. This even works down to a level of specific databases for example.

**Kicker**: This is **not** possible to do in such a granularity from the UI, but the `az` command line accepts assigning the monitoring reader permission on a deep resource ID level, even if the UI for this is not there. By finding the resource ID from the UI, and then using the resource ID from the command line, it's possible to achieve exactly this behaviour.